# Should we merge the encoding and character-encoding tags?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

As the subject indicates, should [encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/encoding) and [character-encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding) be merged?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think so

[encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/encoding) can be about encoding any binary data stream. For example encode a JPG file using Huffman encoding, or encode a video file using some codec. There are a lot of questions about video encoding in that tag

OTOH [character-encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding) is specifically about the encoding of characters, which is a subset of the other tag

I think the tag wiki for [encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/encoding) should be edited. Currently it only talks about character encoding

> The fine art of converting letters into numbers. ASCII, ISO Latin-1, Unicode, EBCDIC… There are dozens of currently used encodings and converting between them is now a witch craft.

The tag wiki for [character-encoding](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/character-encoding) is correct

> A character encoding system consists of a code that pairs each character from a given repertoire with something else — such as a bit pattern, sequence of natural numbers, octets, or electrical pulses — in order to facilitate the transmission of data (generally numbers or text) through telecommunication networks or for data storage.